# Hide JSPs from FacesContext

Tags: java, jsf, servlet-filters

I have a JSF application with a Servlet `Filter` configured for a urlPattern of `/faces/*`.
I want to hide a JSP from faces context so that it won't go through the Servlet `Filter`.
So I kept it under `WebContent` folder of my project as `WebContent/Error.jsp` and declared like the following in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.NullPointerException</exception-type>
    <location>/Error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

But my `Error.jsp` never gets picked up. Instead I see 404 Page not found error.

To be more clear, I want my `Error.jsp` page URL to be:

> http://localhost:8080/myappname/Error.jsp

But it is only reachable by:

> http://localhost:8080/myappname/faces/Error.jsp

The same is the case when I declare any `view-id` in the `faces-config.xml`. Where do I keep the error JSP if I want to hide it from `faces` context?

Comment: I do not understand the role of that filter. What is it doing? Is it also mapped on `ERROR` dispatcher?

Comment: @BalusC-Thanks for the response.In my filter i am looking for attribute in the session.But in Error.jsp such attribute does not exist.So i want to bypass Error.jsp from filter.This is my requirement.I don't know what is ERROR dispatcher.Please explain.

Comment: @BalusC-I understood what a error dispatcher is.My `Error.jsp` should not go through the `filter`.Where should i place `Error.jsp` so that i can remove `faces` from the url?

Comment: Just add an `if` check in the filter? Are you opening it directly or purposefully throwing a NPE? If the filter isn't mapped on `ERROR` dispatcher and you're throwing a NPE upon a normal JSF request, then it shouldn't invoke the filter at all. Hence the confusing nature of your question and my questions in the previous comments.

Comment: My filter isn't mapped on `ERROR` dispatcher and my application throws NPE on normal request only.But my Error.jsp doesn't picked up when i get a NPE.Instead it shows default tomcat stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information given so far, it looks as it should just work fine. You don't have a `<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>` on the filter, so the filter should not be invoked at all whenever the NPE is thrown.

Apparently the NPE got wrapped up in another exception because it's been thrown at an illogical place such as bean's constructor instead of a normal bean action method. In such case, JSF would rethrow it as a `ManagedBeanCreationException`. The container would get it instead of the NPE and thus won't be able to locate the error page. In the container's default HTTP 500 error page, you should read the topmost exception of the stacktrace in order to determine the right exception to define an error page for.

Please keep in mind that runtime exceptions like NPEs are developer errors (bugs!), not production errors and that they should be fixed ASAP. I'd personally just use a global HTTP 500 error page for this kind of bugs:

```xml
<error-page>
    <status-code>500<status-code>
    <location>/errors/generic.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

For more specific, real production exceptions, you can always declare a more specific error page:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.example.YourDatabaseAccessException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/database.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/sessionexpired.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.one more question :) i have one more page called `Logout.jsp` which i am showing after successful logout.Where can i place that to bypass filter?

Comment: Either just put it on a place which doesn't match the `<url-pattern>` of the `Filter`, or (if your `Filter` has an overzealous `/*` pattern), then add an extra `if` check in the `doFilter()` method which should result in just calling `chain.doFilter(request, response)` whenever the request URI is `/contextname/Logout.jsp`.

Comment: My Urlpattern is `/faces/*`.And in the `faces-config.xml`. i have `/Logout.jsp`.But the url for the `Logout.jsp` becomes `http://localhost:8080/myappname/faces/Logout.jsp`. where can i put this `Logout.jsp` to avoid this `faces` in the url.now i have it under `WebContent`.

Comment: If it's a pure JSP page (why not JSF?) just invoke it without `/faces` in URL. I.e. invoke it by a normal `<a>` element or normal `<form>` element instead of a `<h:outputLink>`, `<h:commandLink>` and `<h:form>`. Or if it's a JSF page, just add that `if` check to the filter. However, more normal practice is to map the authentication filter on a more specific URL pattern, such as `/faces/app/*`, `/faces/private/*`, `/faces/secured/*`, etc and put all restricted resources in exactly that `/app`, `/private` or `/secured` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a filter and declear that in your web.xml, all the request will go through that filter, unless you define the filter mapping.

I think you can define a filter mapping in your web.xml as following:

```
<filter> 
<filter-name>URLFilter</filter-name> 
<filter-class>the filter class in your source code</filter-class> 
</filter> 
<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>URLFilter</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/some pages</url-pattern>//skip error.jsp here
</filter-mapping>
```

this is not tested, but just an inspiration.
edit: you can find out more from [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)

Answer (score 0):

To me it doesn't sound like the Faces filter has anything to do with this issue. Can you reach http://localhost:8080/myappname/Error.jsp with the filter completely disabled? If not, then perhaps there is some issue with the Error.jsp file itself?

It's hard to say without seeing the code itself.

Comment: @jsight- Thanks for the response.As you see the above errorpage declaration in `web.xml`, i gave `/Error.jsp`.But `http://localhost:8080/myappname/faces` gets appended in front and url becomes `http://localhost:8080/myappname/faces/Error.jsp`.I am looking for a way to avoid faces in the above url so that this request does not pass through the filter.